# How to change a global variable defined in an included Javascript file from Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

### Background

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to find the answer to this, but this may be from my lack of understanding of `require.js`.

Here's what I'm working with: I have a tightly-coupled legacy enterprise web application, which was written in 2001, using IE 5-specific Javascript at the time. The Javascript file, called `Menu.js`, has functions that enable an HTML table to act like a menu, where table cells are menu items, and some of those menu items can expand sub-menus, which are more table cells.

In short, the code is bad. However, I must provide a band-aid to make this compatible with Chrome and Firefox. The solution is to rewrite the internals of each Javascript function to use jQuery so it'll be cross-browser compatible.

Every web page includes `Menu.js`, and every web page is automatically generated, so I was forced to include jQuery by injecting it from `Menu.js`, which has the following code:

`Menu.js`

```
function injectQuery() {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
  document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

injectJQuery();

function getSubMenu(el) {
  return $(el).find('table')[0] || null;
}

// Other functions are defined here as well

if ( typeof module !=== 'undefined' && module.hasOwnProperty('exports') ) {
  module.exports.getSubMenu = getSubMenu;
}
```

In Jasmine, when testing `Menu.js`, I'm unable to use the `$()` function without getting an undefined error. To get around this, I have the following code:

`menu.spec.js`

```
const sut = require('../src/js/Menu.js');
const testMenu = require('./resources/test.menu').data();

const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = window.window;
const jQuery = require('jquery')(window);

global.$ = jQuery;

describe('getSubMenu()', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = testMenu;
  });

  it('should return the nested sub-menu-3 table given the sub-menu-2 element', () => {
    const subMenu2 = $('#sub-menu-2');
    const result = sut.getSubMenu(subMenu2);

    expect(result.id).toBe('sub-menu-3');
  });
});
```

### Problem

Whenever I run the spec, I get the following error:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
                        ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at injectJquery
```

So, I don't want the `injectJquery()` method defined in `Menu.js` to run when the Jasmine spec runs. I tried the following approaches:

**Attempt 1 - Change the value of a global from Jasmine**

`Menu.js`

```
var isUnderTest = false;

...

if (!isUnderTest) {
  injectJquery();
}

...

if ( typeof module !=== 'undefined' && module.hasOwnProperty('exports') ) {
  ...
  module.exports.isUnderTest = isUnderTest;
}
```

In `menu.spec.js`, I tried setting the following:

```
sut.isUnderTest = true;
```

However, the spec still attempted to execute `injectJquery()` and I received the same error. I tried defining a setter function for the `isUnderTest` variable and calling that, and exporting that function, but I still received the same error.

**Attempt 2 - Use a Jasmine spy to force the function to do nothing**

I tried using a Jasmine spy to make the function do nothing from the spec with the following code:

```
spyOn(sut, 'injectJquery').and.callFake(() => null);
```

And I did export the `injectJquery()` function from within `Menu.js`; however, that didn't work either.

**Attempt 3 - Define a node global variable**

I tried to define a node global variable in `menu.spec.js` like so:

```
global.isUnderTest = true;
```

But, it still didn't work.

### Final Thoughts

Coming from the Java world and using JUnit, I expected my system under test object that I defined in Jasmine to behave similarly like it would for Java, though I know the Javascript file, `Menu.js`, is not an object.

I want `injectJquery()` to run in the browser, but not in the spec. Is there any way to suppress the method call that I'm not seeing?

Comment: you can't include plain `document` javascript to your main file, it needs to be linked to the html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of trial and error, I decided to use a hack-ish way to solve the issue by doing the following:

```
try {
  injectJquery();
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
    // The system is under test: do nothing
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else who is testing legacy Javascript using Jasmine.